# CSS Hexagon with rotating border color

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make a hexagon shape that has a gradient border which rotates.

Example GIF:

[image]

I tried making the shape using CSS only but that did not work because the :after and :before tags use border styles to create the shape, which is a no.

I tried using .svg file and load it as background-image but could not change the border and add css animation to rotate the border

Lastly I tried to insert the GIF but it had problems such as white halo around the shape. My background is dark so that was very visible.

So what's the best way to insert such shape with specified animation?

P.S. Inline svg is not an option since I want to insert the shape simply, like:

`<div id='hex'></div>`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can make use of the gif by using an image editor and removing the alpha channel i.e the white space all around and inside and just keeping the border animation. I'd say gimp is lightweight and pretty good option to consider.

Comment: GIF is the worst case scenario, I'd like this to be CSS if possible.

Comment: Well, you're avoiding SVG as well

Comment: Only the SVG that I have to put inside my HTML. External .svg files are fine

Comment: Also I have no idea why I'm receiving downvotes..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An animated GIF or SVG solution is probably the way to go in this situation.

Buuuuuuuuut, for the sake of experimentation, here's a CSS solution.

Here's the basic idea:

1. Create an element with a hexagonal `clip-mask` to create a hexagon
2. Add an internal element and apply a conical gradient - all credit to this [CSSTricks article](https://css-tricks.com/conical-gradients-css/) on how to do that
3. Apply an animation to make the element with the conical gradient rotate
4. Overlay another, slightly smaller, hexagon, to create the whitespace in the middle

The end effect creates what looks like a border with a rotating gradient.

This has some obvious downsides. For one, it's not transparent, so the inner hexagon color would need to be set to match the elements background, which will only work on solid background colors. The bigger issue is browser support. The `clip-path` property isn't supported across all browsers.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.clip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.50em;
  left: 0.50em;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 94% 23%, 94% 75%, 50% 100%, 5% 75%, 5% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 94% 23%, 94% 75%, 50% 100%, 5% 75%, 5% 25%);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.wheel,
.umbrella,
.color {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 9em;
  height: 9em;
}

.wheel {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 94% 23%, 94% 75%, 50% 100%, 5% 75%, 5% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 94% 23%, 94% 75%, 50% 100%, 5% 75%, 5% 25%);
  width: 9em;
  height: 9em;
  position: relative;
}

.umbrella {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1.4em);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
  will-change: transform;
  animation: 3s linear rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.color,
.color:nth-child(n+7):after {
  clip: rect(0, 9em, 9em, 4.5em);
}

.color:after,
.color:nth-child(n+7) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 4.5em);
  top: calc(50% - 4.5em);
  width: 9em;
  height: 9em;
  clip: rect(0, 4.5em, 9em, 0);
}

.color:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #9ED110;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 12;
}

.color:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #50B517;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 11;
}

.color:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #179067;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 10;
}

.color:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: #476EAF;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 9;
}

.color:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: #9f49ac;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  z-index: 8;
}

.color:nth-child(6):after {
  background-color: #CC42A2;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 7;
}

.color:nth-child(7):after {
  background-color: #FF3BA7;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.color:nth-child(8):after {
  background-color: #FF5800;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.color:nth-child(9):after {
  background-color: #FF8100;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.color:nth-child(10):after {
  background-color: #FEAC00;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.color:nth-child(11):after {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.color:nth-child(12):after {
  background-color: #EDE604;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wheel">
    <ul class="umbrella">
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
      <li class="color"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clip"></div>
</div>
```